# How do Expression Engine plug-ins query and return data when the 'dynamic=' parameter is set to "no"?

Tags: plugin, dynamic, parameters

When I return "entry_id" from my plug-in, I do not want to fetch the "entry_id" of enclosing parent tags.

Channel entries tag does this. How does it work? Thanks.

Comment: We have no idea what you're asking. Can you please rewrite the question? For help on how to ask, see the [FAQ](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

? check if parameter dynamic="no" exist. If is not exist or dynamic="yes" then parse the URL try to find information which can be used as parameters for your plugin.  If dynamic="no" just ignore URL and parser tag parameters only.

That all. If is not what you expected - please rephrase you question.